# gradle build running when no code changed - Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

Using Android Studio I'm debugging app and starting and stopping and running again. Why each time it takes time to "Gradle Build Running" when no code etc. changed bitween runs? Maybe there is some option in Android Studio to fix that?

What about Eclipse (I never used it)? If Eclipse is more time efficient w/out Gradle I'll consider switching developing environments.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Gradle is handling the building and running the environments. So yes every time you run app the Gradle will perform the build operations based on the gradle file.

Well you can find eclipse easy with not having gradle and all But I would not recommend the eclipse cause it is clearly stated in developer.android.com that from now on no new plugins will be released for eclipse.

So as an android developer yes you should use Android Studio.